# Double clicking .txt files causes CMD to startup

Tags: file-extension, file-format, windows-explorer, open-with, default-programs

I think I accidentally set .txt files to open with command prompt when double clicking them.

However I cannot revert this and cause .txt files to open with Notepad++ or notepad using conventional methods do you have any tips on how to fix this?

Right clicking the text file, and choosing notepad++ from the default program menu only leads to noticing that the Always use this program check-box being disabled (grayed out).

Comment: Note: Going to Control Panel\Programs\Default Programs\Set Associations and setting .txt format to notepad or notepad++ also fails, i choose either notepad and notepad++ and after closing the window the current default does not change.

Comment: I'm not sure if this bumps my post up or if this is against the rules, but I was wondering if anybody has any opinions on this?